# How to use Filterset and paginateion in ApiView?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use `PageNumberPagination` and `FilterSet` in `APIView`.
But I have an error below in my code.

> object of type 'ListSerializer' has no len()

How to implement this?

---

Here are the code:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'


class MyFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'


class MyAPIView(views.APIView, PageNumberPagination):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        filterset = MyFilter(request.query_params, queryset=MyModel.objects.all())

        if not filterset.is_valid():
            raise ValidationError(filterset.errors)

        serializer = MySerializer(instance=filterset.qs, many=True)
        paginate_queryset = self.paginate_queryset(serializer, request, view=self)

        return Response(paginate_queryset.data)
```

---

Django 3.2.6

django-filter 22.1

djangorestframework  3.12.4

Python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to make your object inherit from APIView and PageNumberPagination, as one is a view, and the other one, a paginator.
If you want to keep your code as simple as possible, just use a [ListAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview):

```py
class MyAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    filterset_class = MyFilter
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
```

If you want to get this pagination as the default one, you can even [set it as the default pagination style](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#setup) once so you don't have to define it in each of the views that use it.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Pagination on ApiView

#### views.py

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
class EventNewsItems(APIView, PageNumberPagination):
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        event = Event.objects.get(pk=pk)
        news = event.get_news_items().all()
        results = self.paginate_queryset(news, request, view=self)
        serializer = NewsItemSerializer(results, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code and it works

```
class MyAPIView(views.APIView, PageNumberPagination):

    def get(self, request):
        filterset = MyFilter(request.query_params, queryset=MyModel.objects.all())

        results = self.paginate_queryset(filterset.qs, request, view=self)
        serializer = Serializer(results, many=True)

        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Because it works does not mean it's how you should do it. As I said in my answer, making your class inherit from a view and a pagination class is clearly an ugly pattern.